# Is there a faster method to compare string words against a dictionary with anything less than O(n^2)

Tags: javascript, regex, dictionary

Given:

```
sentence = "The world is a great place to live and eat"
dictionary = {
              "ea": "These words rym with each" ,
              "lace": "something"
             }
```

Expected:

```
matched_words --> ["great", "place", "eat"]
```

My approach:
First lookup the dictionary enries and then check for maches in the string

```
Object.entries(dictionary).map(([key]) => {
        let regex = new RegExp(`[a-zA-Z]?${key}[a-zA-Z]?`, "g");
        let keywords = text.match(regex);
        return keywords
}
```

Clarification:
I noticed that my question is confusing.

What I'm working on is something to do with the Arabic language. In Arabic, the definite article "the" of the words is connected to the word.

Example:

"The peace" are two words in English but in Arabic, the definite article "the" is connected to the word making them one word,
"The peace" == "السلام"

What I want is to put some popover definitions of some unused ancient words like Wikipedia[image: the]

So, my approach is to use a dictionary to hold the ancient words and their definitions. Then iterate over the dictionary keys and match the words from a given paragraph with the given keyword. I used regex to ignore the definite article to match the words that contain the keyword.

```
sentence = "السلام عليكم اصدقائي"  
dictionary = { "سلام" : "تعريف السلام"} 

output: ["السلام"]
```

Comment: What is `n` in `O(n²)`? Number of words? Of letters? Of entries in the dictionary?

Comment: of course 'great' doesn't rhyme with 'each'. But seriously the time complexity of regex is not as straightforward as that. All in all this smacks of premature optimization.

Comment: Your approach also leaves you open to duplicate results if multiple keys match the same words in the string. Start by creating a reliable method, and then optimize if necessary.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. If the syntax error is corrected (missing parenthesis + corrected variable name), it produces `[["reat", "eat"], ["place"]]`. So I don't understand why you ask for a faster method. I guess you really want a *working* method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how in detail behind the scenes the effort in terms of an exponential iteration growth or just a multiple times iteration approach really is.

But since one has to use a dynamically to be built regex/pattern anyhow, I would [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the `dictionary`'s [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) array into a string as [alternation](https://javascript.info/regexp-alternation) of a single to be built regex which then gets **[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)ed exactly once** against the OP's `text`.

As for the OP's provided example the created regex then would be ... [`/\b\w*(ea|lace)\w*/g`](https://regex101.com/r/KHTFlt/1).

- `keys` iterates once
- `join` can be counted as a full iteration cycle as well.

**Summary**

Everything boils down to how effective a regex which features alternations does perform.

Thus the OP might need to come up additionally with a performance test in order to figure out whether there are real bottlenecks amongst the different implementations of possible approaches.

```js
const dictionary = {
  ea: "These words rhyme with each" ,
  lace: "something"
};
const text = "The world is a great place to live and eat";

const dictAlternation = Object
  .keys(dictionary)
  .join('|');

console.log({
  dictAlternation,
  regex: RegExp(`\\b\\w*(${ dictAlternation })\\w*`, 'g'),
  matchingResults: text.match(
    RegExp(`\\b\\w*(${ dictAlternation })\\w*\\b`, 'g')
  )
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to sort the keys? Does it matter which key eventually makes a word match, when the output is the whole word? I can't see why that would make a difference. For the rest this seems to be the same answer I posted a few hours earlier.

Comment: @trincot ... I was thinking in terms of e.g. `eal` and `real` matching against `reality` where I would like to be `real` the match instead of `eal`. But thinking about your comment the alternation is applied greedy anyhow, isn't it. Thus thanks for pointing me to that. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @trincot ... and +1 at your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code does not produce the results you expect. If you correct the variable name and add the missing parenthesis, it outputs:

```
[["reat", "eat"], ["place"]]
```

To get the desired result, you would need to change the regex so it matches *more than one* surrounding letter, and returns a one-dimensional array, using `flatMap`:

```js
const text = "The world is a great place to live and eat";
const dictionary = {
    "ea": "These words rhyme with each" ,
    "lace": "something"
};

const results = Object.entries(dictionary).flatMap(([key]) => {
    let regex = new RegExp(`[a-zA-Z]*${key}[a-zA-Z]*`, "g");
    let keywords = text.match(regex);
    return keywords
});
console.log(results);
```

This algorithm still has a flaw: it can return the same word multiple times. This happens when multiple dictionary keys occur in the same word. For instance, if the text has the word "seaplace", it will come out twice.

If this is about rhyming ("rym"?), then you probably don't want to allow vowels *following* the pattern, and neither vowels **immediately** in front of the pattern. Still, the English language is much more complex than that, and two words with "ea" in their final syllable are not guaranteed to rhyme (The words "great", "eat", "near", "bear" and "linear" do not rhyme with each other). But I will leave that for you to define, as your question does not seem to be about the rhyming logic.

You can avoid the explicit loop and rely on one regular expression only, thereby moving the logic to compiled code in the JavaScript engine:

```js
const text = "The world is a great place to live and eat";
const dictionary = {
    "ea": "These words rhyme with each" ,
    "lace": "something"
};

const regex = RegExp(`\\b\\w*(?:${Object.keys(dictionary).join("|")})\\w*`, "gi");

const results = text.match(regex);
console.log(results);
```

Note that this algorithm also ensures that even if a word in the text can match with multiple dictionary keys, it only comes out once.

Comment: I don't know how you understood my problem while my explanation is really crapy. Thank you for the help, this approach opened my eyes to other problems I had in my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it seems like its just the dictionary keys that matter. If that's so, then it's just the well-studied problem called String Searching. If performance really is that important, then you might have to study one of these algorithms and find a library that does it or implement it yourself.

For example, you could use KMP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

The performance for this is O([length of string] + [length of pattern]) for each pattern, or in total, O([length of string] * [# patterns] + [total length of patterns]). There is probably a faster way

Comment: This is a great way to think about the problem. Thanks for the insight